# Related Rates question that I keep getting wrong?

Tags: related-rates

[image: The Problem]

I thought the acceleration would be cosx at x= pi/6, but that’s the wrong answer! Can someone help me here? It’s question three.

Comment: It's homework, and we have unlimited attempts on it. I've already tried to solve this problem two other times. I'm pretty sure I put in .866 both times...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Chain rule.

$t$ for time; $a$ for acceleration.

$a=dv/dt=(dv/dx)(dx/dt)$

Comment: But why would that differ from just finding the derivative of the velocity function?

Comment: $a=\frac{dv}{dt}$ so you need to use the chain rule in the context of implicit differentiation like the answer suggested.the independent variable here is time